# Kotlin Coroutines the right way in Android

Tags: android, async-await, kotlin, coroutine

I'm trying to update a list inside the adapter using async, I can see there is too much boilerplate.

Is it the right way to use Kotlin Coroutines?

can this be optimized more?

```
fun loadListOfMediaInAsync() = async(CommonPool) {
        try {
            //Long running task 
            adapter.listOfMediaItems.addAll(resources.getAllTracks())
            runOnUiThread {
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                progress.dismiss()
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            runOnUiThread {progress.dismiss()}
        } catch (o: OutOfMemoryError) {
            o.printStackTrace()
            runOnUiThread {progress.dismiss()}
        }
    }
```

Comment: **Note: Most of the answers are invalid with the changes in API in the stable release of coroutines.**

Answer (score 46, accepted):

After struggling with this question for days, I think the most simple and clear async-await pattern for Android activities using Kotlin is:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    //...
    loadDataAsync(); //"Fire-and-forget"
}

fun loadDataAsync() = async(UI) {
    try {
        //Turn on busy indicator.
        val job = async(CommonPool) {
           //We're on a background thread here.
           //Execute blocking calls, such as retrofit call.execute().body() + caching.
        }
        job.await();
        //We're back on the main thread here.
        //Update UI controls such as RecyclerView adapter data.
    } 
    catch (e: Exception) {
    }
    finally {
        //Turn off busy indicator.
    }
}
```

The only Gradle dependencies for coroutines are: `kotlin-stdlib-jre7`, `kotlinx-coroutines-android`.

**Note:** Use `job.await()` instead of `job.join()` because `await()` rethrows exceptions, but `join()` does not. If you use `join()` you will need to check `job.isCompletedExceptionally` after the job completes.

To start *concurrent* retrofit calls, you can do this:

```
val jobA = async(CommonPool) { /* Blocking call A */ };
val jobB = async(CommonPool) { /* Blocking call B */ };
jobA.await();
jobB.await();
```

Or:

```
val jobs = arrayListOf<Deferred<Unit>>();
jobs += async(CommonPool) { /* Blocking call A */ };
jobs += async(CommonPool) { /* Blocking call B */ };
jobs.forEach { it.await(); };
```

Comment: Be aware that this basically does the same thing as a non-static AsyncTask, with the same potential issues. You can "fire" it but not "forget" it because it interacts with your Activity at the end. I would recommend that you start the coroutine in onStart() and cancel it in onStop(), to avoid performing work when the Activity is not visible and prevent updating views after the Activity is destroyed. Another solution would be to move the coroutine to a Loader or to a ViewModel (from the Architecture components).

Comment: That is a very good point regarding potential life-cycle issues. I agree that all coroutines (jobs) should be added to a collection of some type, so proper clean-up can be done in onStop(). I also use this "fire-and-forget" approach in response to user actions (button clicks). Thank you for your comment and recommendations.

Comment: Yes, it's not good for Android apps. Try https://proandroiddev.com/android-coroutine-recipes-33467a4302e9

Answer (score 41):

**How to launch a coroutine**

In the `kotlinx.coroutines` library you can start new coroutine using either `launch` or `async` function.

Conceptually, `async` is just like `launch`. It starts a separate coroutine which is a light-weight thread that works concurrently with all the other coroutines.

The difference is that launch returns a `Job` and does not carry any resulting value, while `async` returns a `Deferred` - a light-weight non-blocking future that represents a promise to provide a result later. You can use `.await()` on a deferred value to get its eventual result, but `Deferred` is also a `Job`, so you can cancel it if needed.

**Coroutine context**

In Android we usually use two context:

- `uiContext` to dispatch execution onto the Android main `UI` thread *(for the parent coroutine)*.
- `bgContext` to dispatch execution in background thread *(for the child coroutines)*.

Example

```
//dispatches execution onto the Android main UI thread
private val uiContext: CoroutineContext = UI

//represents a common pool of shared threads as the coroutine dispatcher
private val bgContext: CoroutineContext = CommonPool
```

In following example we are going to use `CommonPool` for `bgContext` which limit the number of threads running in parallel to the value of `Runtime.getRuntime.availableProcessors()-1`. So if the coroutine task is scheduled, but all cores are occupied, it will be queued.

You may want to consider using `newFixedThreadPoolContext` or your own implementation of cached thread pool.

**launch + async (execute task)**

```
private fun loadData() = launch(uiContext) {
    view.showLoading() // ui thread

    val task = async(bgContext) { dataProvider.loadData("Task") }
    val result = task.await() // non ui thread, suspend until finished

    view.showData(result) // ui thread
}
```

**launch + async + async (execute two tasks sequentially)**

Note: task1 and task2 are executed sequentially.

```
private fun loadData() = launch(uiContext) {
    view.showLoading() // ui thread

    // non ui thread, suspend until task is finished
    val result1 = async(bgContext) { dataProvider.loadData("Task 1") }.await()

    // non ui thread, suspend until task is finished
    val result2 = async(bgContext) { dataProvider.loadData("Task 2") }.await()

    val result = "$result1 $result2" // ui thread

    view.showData(result) // ui thread
}
```

**launch + async + async (execute two tasks parallel)**

Note: task1 and task2 are executed in parallel.

```
private fun loadData() = launch(uiContext) {
    view.showLoading() // ui thread

    val task1 = async(bgContext) { dataProvider.loadData("Task 1") }
    val task2 = async(bgContext) { dataProvider.loadData("Task 2") }

    val result = "${task1.await()} ${task2.await()}" // non ui thread, suspend until finished

    view.showData(result) // ui thread
}
```

**How to cancel a coroutine**

The function `loadData` returns a `Job` object which may be cancelled. When the parent coroutine is cancelled, all its children are recursively cancelled, too.

If the `stopPresenting` function was called while `dataProvider.loadData` was still in progress, the function `view.showData` will never be called.

```
var job: Job? = null

fun startPresenting() {
    job = loadData()
}

fun stopPresenting() {
    job?.cancel()
}

private fun loadData() = launch(uiContext) {
    view.showLoading() // ui thread

    val task = async(bgContext) { dataProvider.loadData("Task") }
    val result = task.await() // non ui thread, suspend until finished

    view.showData(result) // ui thread
}
```

---

The complete answer is available in my article [Android Coroutine Recipes](https://proandroiddev.com/android-coroutine-recipes-33467a4302e9)

Answer (score 9):

I think you can get rid of `runOnUiThread { ... }` by using `UI` context for Android applications instead of `CommonPool`.

The `UI` context is provided by the [kotlinx-coroutines-android](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/ui/kotlinx-coroutines-android) module.

Answer (score 6):

We also have another option. if we use [Anko](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko) library , then it looks like this

```
doAsync { 

    // Call all operation  related to network or other ui blocking operations here.
    uiThread { 
        // perform all ui related operation here    
    }
}
```

Add  dependency for Anko in your app gradle like this.

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko:0.10.5"
```

Comment: Can I get the progress of the async task somehow?

Comment: This answer adds additional dependency - anko, which is currently in ver. `0.10.8`. I believe [kotlinx.coroutines](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines) are more than enough to achieve this, what OP asked. Especially in version `1.0.1`.

Comment: Can we use Anko Async in ViewModel. Or it can only be used in activity or fragment.

Answer (score 3):

Like sdeff said, if you use the UI context, the code inside that coroutine will run on UI thread by default. And, if you need to run an instruction on another thread you can use `run(CommonPool) {}`

Furthermore, if you don't need to return nothing from the method, you can use the function `launch(UI)` instead of `async(UI)` (the former will return a `Job` and the latter a `Deferred<Unit>`).

An example could be:

```
fun loadListOfMediaInAsync() = launch(UI) {
    try {
        withContext(CommonPool) { //The coroutine is suspended until run() ends
            adapter.listOfMediaItems.addAll(resources.getAllTracks()) 
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    } catch(e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } catch(o: OutOfMemoryError) {
        o.printStackTrace()
    } finally {
        progress.dismiss()
    }
}
```

If you need more help I recommend you to read the [main guide of kotlinx.coroutines](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/coroutines-guide.md) and, in addition, the [guide of coroutines + UI](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/ui/coroutines-guide-ui.md)

Comment: I couldn't find the method withContext, where's is it from? My kotlin version is 1.2.71

Answer (score 3):

If you want to return some thing from background thread use async

```
launch(UI) {
   val result = async(CommonPool) {
      //do long running operation   
   }.await()
   //do stuff on UI thread
   view.setText(result)
}
```

If background thread is not returning anything

```
launch(UI) {
   launch(CommonPool) {
      //do long running operation   
   }.await()
   //do stuff on UI thread
}
```

Comment: How can I cancel the task like on AsyncTask, with the ability to choose if it's cancelling the task nicely, or with thread-interruption: `https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask#cancel(boolean)` , and how can I check inside that it was cancelled, to stop doing what it does?

Answer (score 2):

All the above answers are right, but I was having a hard time finding the right import for the `UI` from `kotlinx.coroutines`, it was conflicting with `UI` from `Anko`.
Its

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.android.UI
```

Comment: This has been deprecated, can you help with the working one

Comment: See: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines

implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.9"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.9"

Answer (score 1):

Here's the right way to use Kotlin Coroutines. Coroutine scope simply suspends the current coroutine until all child coroutines have finished their execution. This example explicitly shows us how **`child coroutine`** works within **`parent coroutine`**.

An example with explanations:

```
fun main() = blockingMethod {                    // coroutine scope         

    launch { 
        delay(2000L)                             // suspends the current coroutine for 2 seconds
        println("Tasks from some blockingMethod")
    }

    coroutineScope {                             // creates a new coroutine scope 

        launch {
            delay(3000L)                         // suspends this coroutine for 3 seconds
            println("Task from nested launch")
        }

        delay(1000L)
        println("Task from coroutine scope")     // this line will be printed before nested launch
    } 

    println("Coroutine scope is over")           // but this line isn't printed until nested launch completes
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Please find attached the implementation for a remote API call with Kotlin Coroutines & Retrofit library.

```
import android.view.View
import android.util.Log
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import com.test.nyt_most_viewed.NYTApp
import com.test.nyt_most_viewed.data.local.PreferenceHelper
import com.test.nyt_most_viewed.data.model.NytAPI
import com.test.nyt_most_viewed.data.model.response.reviews.ResultsItem
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import javax.inject.Inject

class MoviesReviewViewModel @Inject constructor(
private val nytAPI: NytAPI,
private val nytApp: NYTApp,
appPreference: PreferenceHelper
) : ViewModel() {

val moviesReviewsResponse: MutableLiveData<List<ResultsItem>> = MutableLiveData()

val message: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()
val loaderProgressVisibility: MutableLiveData<Int> = MutableLiveData()

val coroutineJobs = mutableListOf<Job>()

override fun onCleared() {
    super.onCleared()
    coroutineJobs.forEach {
        it.cancel()
    }
}

// You will call this method from your activity/Fragment
fun getMoviesReviewWithCoroutine() {

    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main + handler) {

        // Update your UI
        showLoadingUI()

        val deferredResult = async(Dispatchers.IO) {
            return@async nytAPI.getMoviesReviewWithCoroutine("full-time")
        }

        val moviesReviewsResponse = deferredResult.await()
        this@MoviesReviewViewModel.moviesReviewsResponse.value = moviesReviewsResponse.results

        // Update your UI
        resetLoadingUI()

    }
}

val handler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, exception ->
    onMoviesReviewFailure(exception)
}

/*Handle failure case*/
private fun onMoviesReviewFailure(throwable: Throwable) {
    resetLoadingUI()
    Log.d("MOVIES-REVIEWS-ERROR", throwable.toString())
}

private fun showLoadingUI() {
    setLoaderVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
    setMessage(STATES.INITIALIZED)
}

private fun resetLoadingUI() {
    setMessage(STATES.DONE)
    setLoaderVisibility(View.GONE)
}

private fun setMessage(states: STATES) {
    message.value = states.name
}

private fun setLoaderVisibility(visibility: Int) {
    loaderProgressVisibility.value = visibility
}

enum class STATES {

    INITIALIZED,
    DONE
}
}
```