# Kotlin Coroutines in Android Service

Tags: kotlin, async-await, android-service, kotlin-coroutines

I have an Android service which starts and syncs different types of data with the server when it's online.
I'm new to Kotlin coroutines and I'm trying to accomplish the following:

```
fun syncData{
//Job1 make retrofit call to server
//Job2 make retrofit call to server after job1 is done.
//Job3 make retrofit call to server after job2 is done and so on. 
//After all jobs are done I'll stop service.
}
```

I'm following this post:
[Kotlin Coroutines the right way in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43132080/kotlin-coroutines-the-right-way-in-android)

Which brought me to this solution:

```
fun syncData() = async(CommonPool){
    try{
        val sync1 = async(CommonPool){
            job1.sync()
        }

        val sync2 = async(CommonPool){
            job2.sync()
        }

        val sync3 = async(CommonPool){
            job3.sync()
        }

        val sync4 = async(CommonPool){
            job4.sync()
        }

        job1.await()
        job2.await()
        job3.await()
        job4.await()
    }catch (e: Exception){
    }finally {
        stopSelf()
    }
}
```

But when I get retrofit's log on logcat, every call is mixed. Calls from job3 comes before job1, and so on.
How can I execute them in a pipeline? I'm kinda lost in Kotlin's coroutines so I don't know how exactly to implement this.

Comment: Can you, please, clarify what is the type of `job1`, `job2`, etc variables and what exactly `sync()` function on them is doing?

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: Yeah, kinda. I still used coroutines, because I ended up not needed to await for every result. So it worked great. But the major problem is that every job that I listed is a retrofit call, which is a asynchronous call, but I wanted to wait for every call  to end, that's why I thought async await could provide me a solution.

Answer (score 10):

Agree with [@s1m0nw1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8073652/s1m0nw1) and his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45946804/6121671)

It's a way too hard to approach. All you need is as easy as this:

```
val job = SupervisorJob()

fun syncData() = launch(job) {
    try { 
        val result1 = makeRetrofitCall1()
        val result2 = makeRetrofitCall2(result1)
        ...
        val resultN = makeRetrofitCallN(resultNMinusOne)
    } catch(e: Exception) {
        // handle exception
    } finally {
        stopSelf()
    }
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    job.cancel()
}
```

Here `makeRetrofitCall` means a direct API call as `retrofitClient.getData()` where `retrofitClient` is

```
interface RetrofitClient {

    @GET("endpoint")
    suspend fun getData(): MyCustomResult
}
```

Comment: I'd also launch coroutine with `launch(Dispatchers.IO+job)`

Comment: @Geoffrey It's the same as I did. But instead of IO you should use MainThread if you want to pass data to view and avoid `ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException`

Comment: In this case, `makeRetrofitCallX()` functions have to dispatch.

Answer (score 8):

If you have to execute them *one after the other* and, like you say, they *depend* on each other, it's **not a valid use case for concurrent execution** like you're doing with Coroutines here.
Just do it sequentially, then.

In your example, you're dispatching all tasks at once and wait for their completion. It's totally random which one will be executed first.

It would work if, for example Job1, Job2 and Job3, *were independent of each other* and could *run in parallel.* Then you'd dispatch each of them to a Coroutine and in the end wait for each to complete. You would *not care about the execution order*.

These ideas are independent of coroutines and are valid for every concurrent programming style.

Answer (score 1):

You could add laziness to every `sync()`.

Just change the implementation to this:

```
fun syncData() = async(CommonPool){
        try{
            val sync1 = async(coroutineContext, start = CoroutineStart.LAZY){
                job1.sync()
            }

            val sync2 = async(coroutineContext, start = CoroutineStart.LAZY){
                job2.sync()
            }


            val sync3 = async(coroutineContext, start = CoroutineStart.LAZY){
                job3.sync()
            }

            val sync4 = async(coroutineContext, start = CoroutineStart.LAZY){
                job4.sync()
            }
            job1.await()
            job2.await()
            job3.await()
            job4.await()
        }catch (e: Exception){
        }finally {
            stopSelf()
        }
    }
```

Each job will not execute before the job before it has executed.

Take a look at the [coroutines guide](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/coroutines-guide.md#lazily-started-async).

Comment: the coroutineContext just uses the same context as its parent coroutine context which in this case is the same.